# Консольные приложения на java и kotlin в android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке. Как создать консольные (без интерфейса) приложения на java и kotlin в android studio? Пошаговую инструкцию пожалуйста...
Спасибо!)

Comment: а в чем проблема использовать ide какое-то для таких задач? без интерфейса на android будет процесс какой-то только и все, но смысла в этом маловато мне кажется

Comment: Я пишу под андроид и использую Android studio, и очень часто необходимо писать консольные приложения, а иметь кучу ide под каждый язык с кучей непонятностей в каждой не хочется.

Comment: Можно, конечно, забивать гвозди мясорубкой, особенно, если она уже есть. Но лучше всё-таки обзавестись молотком. Поставьте Intelij IDEA, котороя является основой для АС, поэтому очень похожа, и непонятности там те же самые.

Comment: Ну хорошо, другую ide, но под оба языка с возможностью подключать внешние и вообще любые библиотеки, и вообще вести полноценный многофайловый проект, есть такие?

Comment: Так ведь есть же такая возможность я знаю, почему просто не рассказать о ней? А не вести бесполезные дискусси о гвоздях и мясорубках (((

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду >под оба языка?

Comment: в Adroid studio можно писать на kotlin и java, это и имею в виду

Comment: Вы всегда комментарии наполовину читаете? Я вам уже написал какую ИДЕ вам надо. Бонусом - авторы этой ИДЕ создали и котлин, так что поддержка котлина там лучше, где бы то ни было

Comment: Ну и ставьте Intelij IDEA, в ней это точно есть, и многое другое. Android Studio -та же самая идея. И Kotlin  в IDEA есть и будет хотя бы потому, что их одна компания разрабатывает. Вот ссылка https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Убедили, ставлю IDEA. Спасибо! Хотя, прямо на вопрос так и не ответили (

Comment: Тут в основном нормальные люди, никто такими перверсиями не занимается. Поэтому таких знаний ни у кого нет, т.к. не нужны.

Comment: Для биг дата я иногда использую консольные приложения, для проверки алгоритмов без лишнего "мусора". Понятно объяснил нормальным людям?;)

Comment: Нет такого понятия "консольное приложение для Андроид". Пишите на Kotlin или Java для JVM для своих "биг дата", система Андроид совсем не для этого. Поэтому и пишут вам про мясо в мясорубке и гвозди с молотками :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не будет интерфейса то это вероятнее всего будет сервис. Для того чтобы приложение не запускалось через иконку, вам нужно убрать в манифесте эту строку у активности:

```
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Для фоновой работы вам нужно создать неубиваемую фоновую задачу, которая называется [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#servlife). Вам нужно будет через [BroadCastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) отлавливать события intent. Вот например сервис:

```
public class service extends Service {
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

дальше в манифесте его нужно будет прописать:

```
<service android:name = ".service"/>
```

Ну и дальше уже привязываете действия которые вам нужны. Так же стоит задуматься над тем как воскрешать сервис в случае, если он будет убит системой. Вот есть ссылки где будет полезная информация по моему скромному мнению:

1. [ссылка_1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-background-service-in-android)
2. [ссылка_2](https://guides.codepath.com/android/starting-background-services)
3. [ссылка_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370659/background-application-without-ui)
4. [такая же ситуация на форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219657/how-do-i-keep-a-service-alive-indefinitely)

Надеюсь я вам чем-то помог в решении вашей задачи :)

### UPDATE

проще тогда поставить visual studio code или что-то в таком роде, и там добавить один-два плагина, и делать то что вам нужно) это единственный вариант, чтобы не ставить никаких ide, android studio это довольно серьезная штука, как и все ide. Это крупный инструмент, я думаю если вы пишете приложения, то вы должны понимать что это. Я это к тому говорю, что вам для тестов не нужна вся мощь этого инструмента. Если вам будет хватать какого-то легкого редактора кода типа studio code, то хорошо, нет - ну что же, тогда все-таки нужно будет ставить что-то покрупнее.

Comment: Спасибо, уже кое что! Но хотелось без сервисов и прочих хитростей, а обычное для тестов. В Intelij Idea есть такое, но ее ставить не хочу

Comment: Android studio испольую для разработки по андроид(по прямому назначению) на полную, НО ИНОГДА нужно тестировать косольные приложения для биг дата. К Android studio привык и переходить на что то другое не хочется, тем более что есть эта возможность, но мало кто про нее знает (( хоется узнать. Объяснился;)

Comment: все зависит от уровня консольных приложений)) если это простое приложение то ставьте например studio code, если это сложные приложения то лучше мне кажется idea ставить)

Comment: @Andrew, а где здесь консоль собственно? Консоль подразумевает ввод\вывод информации. С выводом оной еще как-то, а вот как быть с вводом?

Comment: @Юрий, вы нам рассказываете о "биг дата", которые как правило требовательны к ресурсам, какой смысл все это запускать на мобильных устройствах с ограниченной производительностью?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вывод понятно будет, а вводить я думаю можно будет либо через файл либо через сервер, потому что биг дату как-то не с руки вводить вручную))

Comment: Смысл очень простой, не хочется ставить кучу IDE. Перешел на  Intellij IDEA, все работает. А в биг дата делают что то вроде эмулятора ввода(файл, xml, json, БД...да как угодно его можноо оформить), естественно не с таким объемом данных, отлаживают сам алгоритм, а затем отдают на стресс тест с натуральными данными